# How to retrieve healthkit data and display it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a step app. I want to retrieve Healthkit data from the health app, but I don't know how to do it. I can't find anything on the internet. I want to get the steps data from the health app.

Answer (score 11):

**For Asking permission  asking permission**

```
if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
    var writeDataTypes: Set<AnyHashable> = self.dataTypesToWrite()
    var readDataTypes: Set<AnyHashable> = self.dataTypesToRead()
    self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShareTypes: writeDataTypes, readTypes: readDataTypes, completion: {(_ success: Bool, _ error: Error) -> Void in
        if !success {
            print("You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: \(error). If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.")
            return
        }
    })
}
```

**To write Data**

```
func dataTypesToWrite() -> Set<AnyHashable> {
    var heightType: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)
    var weightType: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)
    var systolic: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)
    var dystolic: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)
    return Set<AnyHashable>([heightType, weightType, systolic, dystolic])
}
```

**To read data from health kit**

```
func dataTypesToRead() -> Set<AnyHashable> {
    var heightType: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)
    var weightType: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)
    var systolic: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)
    var dystolic: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)
    var sleepAnalysis: HKCategoryType? = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .sleepAnalysis)
    var step: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
    var walking: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)
    var cycling: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceCycling)
    var basalEnergyBurned: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .basalEnergyBurned)
```

**If you want to get the step count for last week then you can follow this bellow code**

```
self.healthStore = HKHealthStore()
var calendar = Calendar.current
var interval = DateComponents()
interval.day = 1
var anchorComponents: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
anchorComponents?.hour = 0
var anchorDate: Date? = calendar.date(fromComponents: anchorComponents)
var quantityType: HKQuantityType? = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
    // Create the query
var query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate, intervalComponents: interval)
// Set the results handler
query.initialResultsHandler = {(_ query: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery, _ results: HKStatisticsCollection, _ error: Error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        // Perform proper error handling here
        print("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error?.localizedDescription) ***")
    }
    var endDate = Date()
    var startDate: Date? = calendar.date(byAddingUnit: .day, value: -7, to: endDate, options: 0)
    // Plot the daily step counts over the past 7 days
    results.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate, block: {(_ result: HKStatistics, _ stop: Bool) -> Void in
        var quantity: HKQuantity? = result.sumQuantity()
        if quantity != nil {
            var date: Date? = result.startDate
            var value: Double? = quantity?.doubleValue(forUnit: HKUnit.count())
            totalStepsCount = String(format: "%.f", value)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                self.calculateStepCountAndShow()
            })
            print("\(date): \(value)")
        }
    })
}
self.healthStore.executeQuery(query)
}
```

Comment: once the query is executed, how can I send it back to my JS file?? Any inputs mate

Answer (score 3):

There are many tutorials on internet to use `healthkit`

to setup healthkit in your app and for permissions follow one of these tutorials

1. follow official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit)
2. Appcoda's [HealthKit introduction](http://www.appcoda.com/healthkit-introduction/)
3. Sample app [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/sleep-analysis-healthkit/) and
4. [Raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started)

for example if we want to retrieve sleeping analysis data,

```
func retrieveSleepAnalysis() {

    // first, we define the object type we want
    if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryTypeForIdentifier(HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis) {

        // Use a sortDescriptor to get the recent data first
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        // we create our query with a block completion to execute
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: nil, limit: 30, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                // something happened
                return

            }

            if let result = tmpResult {

                // do something with my data
                for item in result {
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        let value = (sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.InBed.rawValue) ? "InBed" : "Asleep"
                        print("Healthkit sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) - value: \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // finally, we execute our query
        healthStore.executeQuery(query)
    }
}
```

Comment: once the query is executed, how can I send it back to my JS file?? Any inputs mate

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `healthkit` from project `capabilities`
then you will go through `authentication` process, then you will start implementing a `query` to retrieve the data using `HKSampleQuery` , kindly follow [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started)

as the code is long to be included here :)